# Ansible looping with conditions

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have bit problems to understand conditions looping.
I'm getting `REST API` response from Ambari server.
This response contains `JSON` with service names on host.
I'd like to iterate over service names to do some tasks.

Here are my steps in Ansible:

```
## This gets http api responce.
## in components I'm getting full `json`
- name: Get Hadoop services
  uri:
    url: ' {{ Ambari_link }}/{{ clustername }}/hosts/{{ ansible_host }}/host_components/ '
    method: GET
    headers:
      X-Requested-By: ambari
    user: "{{ Ambari_Admin_User}}"
    password: "{{ Ambari_Admin_Pass }}"
    force_basic_auth: yes
  register: components
```

Here is step that outputs service names

```
## Here I'm simply list all services on host in cluster.
- name: "Display all services"
  debug:
    msg: " {{ Ambari_link }}/{{ clustername }}/host_components/{{ item }} "
  loop: "{{ components.json | json_query('items[*].HostRoles.component_name') }}"
```

Example output

```
ok: [slave] => (item=DATANODE) => {
    "msg": " https://ambari-server:8443/api/v1/clusters/test_cluster/host_components/DATANODE "
}
ok: [slave] => (item=HDFS_CLIENT) => {
    "msg": " https://ambari-server:8443/api/v1/clusters/test_cluster/host_components/HDFS_CLIENT "
}
ok: [slave] => (item=NODEMANAGER) => {
    "msg": " https://ambari-server:8443/api/v1/clusters/test_cluster/host_components/NODEMANAGER "
}
ok: [slave] => (item=YARN_CLIENT) => {
    "msg": " https://ambari-server:8443/api/v1/clusters/test_cluster/host_components/YARN_CLIENT "
}
```

Now part that i don't understand how to implement.
I'd like to iterate over all service names.
If service name contains `_CLIENT` `ansible` should proceed with new `item`.
If service name does not contains `_CLIENT` in should print debug message. 
But this step is simply skipped

```
- name: Filter Clients
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ components.json | json_query('items[*].HostRoles.component_name') }}"
  when:  " item.find('CLIENT') == 'CLIENT' "
```

I also tried to search only for DATANODE but it was also skipped step.

```
when:  " item.find('DATANODE') == 'DATANODE' "
```

Can some one please explain how to search in item for `_CLIENT` and why it is skipped?

Comment: Did you check the result of `item.find('DATANODE')` for match and no match ? Can it be equal to `DATANODE` in any case ? => answer: no because `find` is returning an integer. There are anyway [better options to these kind of checks this in ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings)

Comment: No. I haven't tested. I thought that `.find` is searching for sub string. I have changed to `item.find('DATANODE')==1` but it still skips this step completly.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_find.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have as usual over complicated simplest part.
Instead of

```
when:  " item.find('DATANODE') == 'DATANODE' "
```

It is possible to use

```
when: not '_CLIENT' in item
=> returns DATANODE, NODEMANAGER
```

Or more generic

```
# item contains [foo,bar]
when: not 'oo' in item
=> Returns all that not contains oo
```